# Using position of a free particle to measure time

Tags: gravity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, time

Hartle, *gravity*

> An observer in an inertial frame can discover a parameter t with
> respect to which the positions of all free particles are changing at constant rates.
> This is time

Then goes on to say

> Indeed, inertial frames
> could be defined as Cartesian reference frames for which Newton’s first law holds
> in the form  $\mathbf{\ddot r}=0$
> Using the laws of mechanics, an observer in an inertial frame can construct a
> clock that measures the time $t$. For instance, the position of one free particle could
> be used to measure $t$, since its position changes at a constant rate in $t$

Using the position of one free particle to measure time, how does that guarantee that for other free particles this definition of time leads to$\mathbf{\ddot r}=0$

To establish I've a inertial frame I've to find that free particles move in straight lines and the double derivative with respect to a parameter, call it  $a$, is zero for all the particles.

So I've to search for a parameter $a$ that gives $d^2 r/da =0$ for all the free particles.

The author chooses $a$ as related to the  distance of one particular free particle and says this can be used to measure time.

But how does one know that we choose the correct paramete?

We were guaranteed that there exists a parameter such that $d^2 r/da =0$ but it didn't tell me that the position of one free particle is a correct parameter.

Comment: Free particle means no force, so r''=0 and all free particles follow Newtons first law law

Comment: Forgive this question, but the scenario seems so unattainable and unrealistic that it might be no more than a thought-experiment -- e.g. posed as a homework problem?